# PHP PDO workflow

Tags: php, pdo

I've been using PDO for quite some while now, but I'm wondering whether I'm checking for errors too much or not enough. This is how my stuff generally looks:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT something FROM table WHERE field=:field AND field2=:field2");
$STH->bindParam(":field",$field);
$STH->bindParam(":field2",$field2);
if($STH->execute()){
    if($STH->rowCount() == 1){
       echo "This is what is returned";
    }else{
       echo "Something went wrong.";
    }
}else{
   echo "Something went wrong.";
}
```

Of course the `$STH->rowCount()`-check depends on what I'm expecting. For example when a user logs in, only one result can be found with that username. Now of course this is already checked in the database, yet I double check it here again. Is this necesary?

Also the `if(STH->execute())`-check I'm not sure if it's really necessary. What are the best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation 'http://php.net/pdostatement.rowcount' it's a bad practice to use **rowcount** with SELECT statements because many databases can not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. For checking user it's better to use:

**Select count(*) ..... and PDOStatement:execute + PDOStatement:fetchColumn.**

Also keep in mind **(STH->execute()** doesn't check anything it only says that your query is executed without errors.